# when I using yield in fixture the yield value return null

Tags: null, pytest, yield

I was asked to write a log that shows an error after a test has taken place, for this I used
fixture in *conftest.py* file.
My code:

```py
pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def log_during_fails(request):
    outcome = yield  
    result = outcome.get_result()

    if result.when == "call":
        if result. Failed == True:
            logging.info("test passed successfully")
        else:
            logging.info("trace:", result)
```

Unfortunately I get an error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_result'"
I tried to print the result and and I came to know that it contains value `None`, therefore, the function cannot be run on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the conftest makereport hook. This hook allows you to capture data about each test you run.

For more information on conftest and all of its usages, see the pytest documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html

This question has been answered before on this site, but here is what it would look like:

conftest.py

```py
import pytest
import logging


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    report = yield
    result = report.get_result()

    if result.when == 'call':
        (filename, line, name) = item.location
        test = item.nodeid
        status_tag = result.outcome
        line = line
        duration = call.duration
        exception = call.excinfo
        if result.outcome == 'failed':
            logging.error(f"TEST: {test} {status_tag} on LINE: {line} with EXCEPTION: {exception} ---- DURATION: {duration}")
        else:
            logging.info(f"TEST: {test} PASSED")
```

After each test this hook will run and gather the results of the test. Then the if/else will decide if the test was a pass or fail.